# How to grep data from one file, do small operation and then append them into another file

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have two files
**One is(case1):**

```
Automatically generated mesh
      10
Reciprocal lattice
    0.00000000000000    0.00000000000000    0.00000000000000             1
    0.20000000000000   -0.00000000000000   -0.00000000000000             8
    0.40000000000000   -0.00000000000000   -0.00000000000000             8
    0.20000000000000    0.20000000000000   -0.00000000000000             6
    0.40000000000000    0.20000000000000   -0.00000000000000            24
   -0.40000000000000    0.20000000000000    0.00000000000000            24
   -0.20000000000000    0.20000000000000    0.00000000000000            12
    0.40000000000000    0.40000000000000   -0.00000000000000             6
   -0.40000000000000    0.40000000000000    0.00000000000000            12
   -0.40000000000000    0.40000000000000    0.20000000000000            24
```

**and the other is(case2)**

```
   0.06309051 -0.03237807  0.05437503       0.017
   0.06309051 -0.03642533  0.05151319       0.017

 k-points in reciprocal lattice and weights: K-Path Generated.
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000       0.017
   0.05555556  0.00000000  0.05555556       0.017
   0.11111111  0.00000000  0.11111111       0.017
   0.16666667  0.00000000  0.16666667       0.017
   0.22222222  0.00000000  0.22222222       0.017
   0.27777778  0.00000000  0.27777778       0.017
   0.33333333  0.00000000  0.33333333       0.017
   0.38888889  0.00000000  0.38888889       0.017
   0.44444444  0.00000000  0.44444444       0.017
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.50000000       0.017
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.50000000       0.017
   0.51388889  0.02777778  0.51388889       0.017
   0.52777778  0.05555556  0.52777778       0.017
   0.54166667  0.08333333  0.54166667       0.017
   0.55555556  0.11111111  0.55555556       0.017
   0.50000000  0.02777778  0.52777778       0.017
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.50000000       0.017

 position of ions in fractional coordinates (direct lattice)
```

I need to

1. grep the data between `k-points in reciprocal lattice and weights: K-Path Generated.` and first blank line after it `(i.e. before the row having position of ions in fractional coordinates (direct lattice))` from
   **case2 file** and make the last column `0`
2. count the total number of rows from **case1 file** after `Reciprocal lattice` and total number of rows in the **file grepped in step 1** and then
   update this number with the number available in second row of **case1
   file** (**here it is 10 but it may vary**)
3. append the grepped data from 1st step in **file 1st.** and copy the 1st file as KPOINTS

The final **KPOINTS** file should be

```
Automatically generated mesh
      27
Reciprocal lattice
    0.00000000000000    0.00000000000000    0.00000000000000             1
    0.20000000000000   -0.00000000000000   -0.00000000000000             8
    0.40000000000000   -0.00000000000000   -0.00000000000000             8
    0.20000000000000    0.20000000000000   -0.00000000000000             6
    0.40000000000000    0.20000000000000   -0.00000000000000            24
   -0.40000000000000    0.20000000000000    0.00000000000000            24
   -0.20000000000000    0.20000000000000    0.00000000000000            12
    0.40000000000000    0.40000000000000   -0.00000000000000             6
   -0.40000000000000    0.40000000000000    0.00000000000000            12
   -0.40000000000000    0.40000000000000    0.20000000000000            24
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000       0
   0.05555556  0.00000000  0.05555556       0
   0.11111111  0.00000000  0.11111111       0
   0.16666667  0.00000000  0.16666667       0
   0.22222222  0.00000000  0.22222222       0
   0.27777778  0.00000000  0.27777778       0
   0.33333333  0.00000000  0.33333333       0
   0.38888889  0.00000000  0.38888889       0
   0.44444444  0.00000000  0.44444444       0
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.50000000       0
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.50000000       0
   0.51388889  0.02777778  0.51388889       0
   0.52777778  0.05555556  0.52777778       0
   0.54166667  0.08333333  0.54166667       0
   0.55555556  0.11111111  0.55555556       0
   0.50000000  0.02777778  0.52777778       0
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.50000000       0
```

Comment: Okay, where are you stuck? `awk` can handle the whole thing.

Comment: I am stuck at step 1.

Comment: Isolate the records in case2 with `awk '/k-points/ {n=1; next}; NF==0 {n=0}; n {sub($NF,"0"); print}' case2` Confirm that is what you need from case2, then instead of printing the output, save to an array and move to step 2. (you can use the array index as your counter) `n` is just a flag that when set to `1` collects the records after the `"k-points"` line until a blank line `$NF == 0` is found and the `n` is set back to zero.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you continue to add to my original comment, you can build a short `awk` script that will handle the entire conversion for you. You essentially have two sets of rules. The rules for the `case2` file which we will read first and where you can compare that the `FNR` (file record number) is equal to the `NR` (number of records) meaning you are reading the first file.

For the second file to read, `case1`, the `NR` continues to increment, so your current `FNR` is no longer equal to the total `NR` -- which is a convenient way to process each of the files differently in the same script.

For both `case2` and `case1` files, you could do:

```
awk '
    NR==FNR && /k-points/ { c2=1; next }
    NR==FNR && !NF { m=c2; c2=0 }
    NR==FNR && c2  { sub($NF,"0"); b[c2++] = $0 }
    
    NR!=FNR && /Reciprocal/ { n=1; next } 
    NR!=FNR && n  { a[n++] = $0 }
END {
    print "Automatically generated mesh"
    print "       " m + n - 2
    print "Reciprocal lattice"
    for (i=1; i<n; i++)
        print a[i]
    for (i=1; i<m; i++)
        print b[i]
}' case2 case1
```

**Example Use/Output**

You can just select the code above and then middle-mouse-paste it into an xterm with the current directory containing the two files `case2` and `case1` to test:

```
$ awk '
>     NR==FNR && /k-points/ { c2=1; next }
>     NR==FNR && !NF { m=c2; c2=0 }
>     NR==FNR && c2  { sub($NF,"0"); b[c2++] = $0 }
>
>     NR!=FNR && /Reciprocal/ { n=1; next }
>     NR!=FNR && n  { a[n++] = $0 }
> END {
>     print "Automatically generated mesh"
>     print "       " m + n - 2
>     print "Reciprocal lattice"
>     for (i=1; i<n; i++)
>         print a[i]
>     for (i=1; i<m; i++)
>         print b[i]
> }' case2 case1
Automatically generated mesh
       27
Reciprocal lattice
    0.00000000000000    0.00000000000000    0.00000000000000             1
    0.20000000000000   -0.00000000000000   -0.00000000000000             8
    0.40000000000000   -0.00000000000000   -0.00000000000000             8
    0.20000000000000    0.20000000000000   -0.00000000000000             6
    0.40000000000000    0.20000000000000   -0.00000000000000            24
   -0.40000000000000    0.20000000000000    0.00000000000000            24
   -0.20000000000000    0.20000000000000    0.00000000000000            12
    0.40000000000000    0.40000000000000   -0.00000000000000             6
   -0.40000000000000    0.40000000000000    0.00000000000000            12
   -0.40000000000000    0.40000000000000    0.20000000000000            24
   0.00000000  0.00000000  0.00000000       0
   0.05555556  0.00000000  0.05555556       0
   0.11111111  0.00000000  0.11111111       0
   0.16666667  0.00000000  0.16666667       0
   0.22222222  0.00000000  0.22222222       0
   0.27777778  0.00000000  0.27777778       0
   0.33333333  0.00000000  0.33333333       0
   0.38888889  0.00000000  0.38888889       0
   0.44444444  0.00000000  0.44444444       0
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.50000000       0
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.50000000       0
   0.51388889  0.02777778  0.51388889       0
   0.52777778  0.05555556  0.52777778       0
   0.54166667  0.08333333  0.54166667       0
   0.55555556  0.11111111  0.55555556       0
   0.50000000  0.02777778  0.52777778       0
   0.50000000  0.00000000  0.50000000       0
```

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: That's a lot of single-letter variable names (a, b, m, n, c2) - some meaningful names would make the code much easier to understand. And why `c2` instead of just `c` (irrelevant  if you rename it of course)? Also consider creating a single `NR==FNR{...next}` block so you don't have to test `NR==FNR` 3 times and `NR!=FNR` twice.

Comment: @EdMorton - yes that is very true. I had started with array1, array2, but then the one-liner I was testing with got long... I will resist that temptation in the future `:)`

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk:

```
awk 'FNR==NR && /^Reciprocal lattice/ { scnt=1;next } FNR==NR && scnt==1 { cnt++;map1[FNR]=$0 } NR != FNR  && /^$/ { scnt1=0 } FNR != NR  && / k-points in reciprocal lattice and weights: K-Path Generated./ { scnt1=1;next } FNR != NR && scnt1==1 { cnt++;gsub($4,"0",$4);map[FNR]=$0 } END { PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";print "Automatically generated mesh";printf "\t%s\n",cnt;print "Reciprical lattice";for (i in map1) { print map1[i] } for (i in map) { print map[i] } }' case1 case2
```

Explanation:

```
awk 'FNR==NR && /^Reciprocal lattice/ {                        # Process the first file (FNR==NR). Where the line start with "Reciprocal lattice" set a marker variable scnt to 1
              scnt=1;
              next 
            } 
     FNR==NR && scnt==1 {                                       # Where it is the first file and marker scnt is 1, process
              cnt++;                                            # Increment a total line counter
              map1[FNR]=$0                                      # Set up a map array with the file record number the index and the line ($0) the value
            }
     NR != FNR  && /^$/ {                                       # Process where we encounter the second file (NR != FNR) and the line is blank
              scnt1=0                                           # Set second tracking variable scnt1 to 0
            } 
     FNR != NR  && / k-points in reciprocal lattice and weights: K-Path Generated./ { 
              scnt1=1;                                          # Where it is the second file and we see the text "k-point ...", set second tracking variable scnt1 to 1
              next 
            } 
     FNR != NR && scnt1==1 {                                     # Process where second file and second tracking variable is 1
              cnt++;                                             # Increment total line count
              gsub($4,"0",$4);                                   # Use gsub to replace the 4th field with 0
              map[FNR]=$0                                        # Set up another array map with the file number record as the index and the amended line as the value
             } 
         END {                                                   # Process at the end of processing both files.
              PROCINFO["sorted_in"]="@ind_num_asc";              # Set the array ordering
              print "Automatically generated mesh";                            
              printf "\t%s\n",cnt;print "Reciprical lattice";    # Print text and total
              for (i in map1) { 
                 print map1[i]                                   # Loop through map1 and print lines
              } 
              for (i in map) { 
                 print map[i]                                    # Loop through map and print lines
              } 
             }' case1 case2
```

Comment: It did not work. Thank you for your time. Suggestion given by Mr. David worked partly.

Comment: No worries. I can verifiy that the solution works using GNU awk 4.0.2 and the sample you posted.

Comment: ahh, I know now. I do not have gnuplot on my cluster and also I will not be able to install gnu on it. Thats why it did not work for me.